# http error 405 method is not allowed slidetoggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to use SlideToggle() method in my page and this script

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
  <button id="button">button</button>
  <p class="align">text</p>
  <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#button").click(function(){
               $(".align").slideToggle(800);
           });
       });
  </script>
```

Works perfectly until I insert it into my page. When I press the button I have 405 method is not allowed (with webmatrix) and just nothing when I run page from windows explorer. 
I don't use any other js with that page. Maybe someone has already faced this issue?

Comment: Where are you seeing this error?

Comment: Why exactly do you think that this is caused by `slideToggle()` call? Does that error really disappear once you remove the whole `<script>`? I'd say that the button itself is just submitting to a bogus form action URL which doesn't accept the issued HTTP method as specified in `<form method>`

Comment: The HTTP response `405 Method Not Allowed` is issued when you try to use a request type that the server won't accept - for example, doing a `POST` to a URL that only accepts `GET` and `HEAD` requests.

Comment: it appeares when i press the button, everything else is fine...

Comment: in Chrome and Firefox, both last versions

Comment: Yes ... And what if you remove the whole `<script>`? I just don't believe that it's caused by simply adding that script. In other words, this is more likely just a misobservation of the concrete problem and thus completely unrelated to JS/jQuery.

Comment: Well I don't have any mistake when I run page without any server, it just starts moving and then throws me to the top of the page.
when I remove script everything is working, and script works apart from this page.

Comment: If the `<button>` is inside a `<form>` the default behavior is for it to act as a `<button type="submit">` which will try to submit the form to whatever server is specified by the `action` attribute. That could be the cause of the `405`. Try returning `false` from the event handler or better yet change `type="button"`.